# Using ByRef and ByVal

Tags: vb.net, byref, byval

I'm fairly new to programming and I was told that I should be passing things using ByRef and ByVal, but when I do so, I get an error saying:

```
Error   3   Method 'Private Sub Activate_Click(ByRef intIDToChange As Integer, sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' 
cannot handle event 'Public Event Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' because they do not have a compatible signature.  
F:\Dropbox\Gooby Backup\School Work\Computing\Unit 4\Room Booking Client\WindowsApplication1\ActivateDeactivate\Activate Deactivate.vb  32  129 WindowsApplication1
```

I start my sub with:

```
Private Sub Activate_Click(ByRef intIDToChange As Integer, sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Activate.Click
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't handle `Activate.Click` with your method, because you have additional `Integer` parameter which is not compatible with Event signature.

**Event signature**

```
Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
```

**Your method**

```
Activate_Click(ByRef intIDToChange As Integer, sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your method as

`Private Sub Activate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Activate.Click`

because the button click event takes only two arguments.

If you want to use the variable `intIDToChange`, provide that as a class level variable like

`private intIDToChange as Integer` and update it in `Activate_Click`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the event handler you've declared there (Activate_Click) doesn't match the event definition for ActivateClick.

Try changing to:

```
Private Sub Activate_Click(ByVal intIDToChange As Integer, ....) Handles Activate.Click
```

ByVal sends the value of the variable via the parameter, whereas ByRef sends the variable (meaning changes made in the subroutine affect the calling routines variable).

More detailed answer here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/07b9d3b9-5658-49ed-9218-005564e8209e/

Comment: Would it be better to declare variables inside the form load sub, then reference them from there?

Comment: It's better to declare outside single methods and reference them inside your method via a Me.FieldName route.If you're using those values across your application or within the class defining this particular event hook maybe consider wrapping them in an appropriate context (pressed 'enter' prematurely so had to edit comment!)

Comment: ...also just had a coffee and spotted my answer isn't correct re: event hook definition: @MarcinJuraszek answer is